# C - portable fast dot product between a float matrix and a sparse boolean value matrix

Tags: c, performance, matrix, linear-algebra

I am working on a spiking neural network project in C where spikes are boolean values. Right now I have built a custom bit matrix type to represent the spike matrixes.

I frequently need the dot product of the bit matrix and a matrix of single precision floats of the same size, so I was wondering how I should speed things up?

I also need to do pointwise multiplication of the float matrix and the bit matrix later.

My plan right now was just to loop through with and if statement and bitshift. I want to speed this up.

```
float current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n_elem; i++, bit_vec >>= 1) {
    if (bit_vec & 1)
        current += weights[i];
}
```

I don't necessarily need to use a bit vector, it could be represented in other ways too. I have seen other answers here, but they are hardware specific and I am looking for something that can be portable.

I am not using any BLAS functions either, mostly because I am never operating on two floats. Should I be?

Thanks.

Comment: How sparse is your matrix? You don't use that fact at all. It might be faster to keep a list of `true` indexes.

Comment: Unfortunately it is unpredictable, although the matrix is never more than a hundred elements. Wouldn't finding the true indexes take the same number of steps?

Comment: If you have a matrix of a hundred elements and it is really sparse (for example, under 10), you could have a list (vector?) of those indexes and save 90% of checks.

Comment: Ah I understand. Unfortunately, I don't know the indexes of the elements beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bit_vec >>= 1` and `current += weights[i]` instruction cause a loop carried dependency that will certainly prevent the compiler to generate a fast implementation (and also prevent the processor to execute it efficiently).
You can solve this by **unrolling the loop**. Additionally, most mainstream compilers are not smart enough so to optimize out the condition en use a *blend instruction* available on most architecture. *Conditional branches are slow*, especially when they cannot be easily *predicted* (which is certainly you case). You can use a multiplication so to help the compiler generating better instructions. Here is the result:

```c
    const unsigned int blockSize = 4;
    float current[blockSize] = {0.f};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n_elem-blockSize+1; i+=blockSize, bit_vec >>= blockSize)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < blockSize ; ++j)
            current[j] += weights[i] * (bit_vec >> j);

    for (; i < n_elem; ++i, bit_vec >>= 1)
        if (bit_vec & 1)
            current[0] += weights[i];

    float sum = 0.f;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < blockSize ; ++j)
        sum += current[j];
```

This code should be faster assuming `n_elem` is relatively big. It should still be far from being efficient since compilers like GCC and Clang fail to **auto-vectorize** it. This is sad since it would be several time faster with **SIMD instructions** (like SSE, AVX, Neon, etc.). That being said, this is exactly why people use non-portable code: to manually use efficient instruction since compiler often fail to do that in non-trivial cases.